# Any materials to study EVM?

Tags: evm

Do you guys have any resources to study EVM?
I already looked at the official document, but still vague in what is EVM. Any materials to learn EVM is appreciated!

Comment: This is the only article you need to visit, you'll find the best resources. https://www.zaryabs.com/evm-learning-resources/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good question. There are few EVM learning resources because it is an advanced, modern, topic in a niche industry. Most people who work with EVM already have an understanding of Virtual Machine architectures and can directly work with EVM implementation source code and so-called [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

- The first step would be to do some real trades on Ethereum chains and explore them with Etherscan to get concrete experience on how EVM works
- EVM is not much different from any other virtual machine, outside the fact that it is bolted on a blockchain
- The easiest to read, and also the reference implementation of EVM, is [Pv-EVM](https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm). There you can simply read the source code and unit test code to see how it is put together.

Note that virtual machines are an advanced topic and there won't be any tutorial style material "this is how I create my own EVM." Blockchains are one of the most advanced topics in computer science, so it is recommendable that before diving into EVM, one has a solid background in computer sciences.

Answer (score 4):

Learning the same thing at the moment, I'll be glad to share some amazing resources i found:

- [A awesome list of  great EVM learning resources](https://www.devpill.me/docs/smart-contract-development/evm-deep-dive/)
- [An other list of curated EVM learning resources](https://noxx3xxon.notion.site/noxx3xxon/The-EVM-Handbook-bb38e175cc404111a391907c4975426d)
- [The go to tool for learning and using EVM, with playground, opcodes list, precompiled contracts...](https://www.evm.codes/playground)
- [The best deep dive explanation I found on EVM, in 5 parts](https://noxx.substack.com/p/evm-deep-dives-the-path-to-shadowy?s=r)
- [Great visual explanation of EVM for those who need to see it](https://takenobu-hs.github.io/downloads/ethereum_evm_illustrated.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

- https://www.makeuseof.com/beginners-guide-ethereum-virtual-machine/
- https://cryptodevhub.io/ethereum-virtual-machine-tutorials

Hoping these will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many resources to learn about EVM.
This could be a good start
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/